# Sass is having hard time parsing a CSS RGB syntax

Tags: css, sass

Just plugged in `gulp-sass` into an existing project, and I'm getting an error when I try to write an RGB syntax as follows:

```
rgb(70 168 255 / 0.05)
```

The  log:

```
[17:51:58] Starting 'compileCSS'...
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    src/xxx.css
Error: Function rgb is missing argument $green.
        on line 77 of src/xxx.css
>>     background-color: rgb(70 168 255 / 0.05);
```

This is a valid CSS sytnax (which my chrome apparently decided it should be my default syntax). Am I forced to replace all of the occurrences with commas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Update:

`dart-sass` has been deprecated in favor of `sass`

---

According to sass, `node-sass` doesn't support color level 4. Therefore, I used the `dart-sass` compiler instead.

Answer (score 8):

Use `sass` instead of `node-sass`.

```
% npm uninstall node-sass
% npm install sass
```